# Jquery delay Unhandled Error

Tags: jquery, delay

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function margin(){
    $('.logo').animate({ marginLeft : "150px"}, 1500).delay(4000).animate({ marginLeft : "350px"}, 1500, function() { 
        delay(4000).margin(); 
    }); 
}
margin();
});
```

I want my code to loop infinitely, but it doesn't work. 
Firebug's console says: 'Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: delay' (4th line). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay` appear `undefined` ? Try substituting `$.fn.delay`  for calling `undefined` `delay` function ; utilizing `.queue()` to call `margin` recursively

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function margin() {
    $(".logo").animate({
        marginLeft: "150px"
      }, 1500).delay(4000)
      .animate({
        marginLeft: "350px"
      }, 1500, function() {
        $(this).delay(4000, "margin")
          .queue("margin", margin).dequeue("margin");
      });
  }
  margin();
});
```

```css
.logo {
  background: olive;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="logo">abc</div>
```